# facebook developers

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

Will facebook developer interface less about adding staff or not join officers difference?

The different nature of the staff joined what functionality?

please give me some advice,thank you...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to read the documentation on security roles.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/